# Dropwizard: customize health check address and format

Tags: dropwizard

Is it possible to customize Dropwizrd's healthcheck output so that, e.g.: `/health` for healthchecks instead of `/healthcheck` and some output like `{“status”: 200}`.

I realise I could simply write a new resource that does what ever I need, I was just wondering if there is a more standard way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I have read on the 0.7.1 source code it's not possible to change the resource URI for healthchecks unfortunately, I highly doubt you can change the healthcheck format. I also remember people complaining about not being able to add REST resources to admin page, only servlets. Maybe on 0.8.0?

**Here are the details of what I've tracked so far on the source code. Maybe I have misread or misunderstood something, so somebody could fix it.**

Metrics has actually written [AdminServlet](https://github.com/dropwizard/metrics/blob/master/metrics-servlets/src/main/java/com/codahale/metrics/servlets/AdminServlet.java) to add healtcheck servlet in a way that it checks the servlet config whether the URI is defined or not.

```
this.healthcheckUri = getParam(config.getInitParameter(HEALTHCHECK_URI_PARAM_KEY), DEFAULT_HEALTHCHECK_URI);
```

But dropwizard doesn't provide a way to inject this configuration in any way on [AbstractServerFactory](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/4edb0ce30ad82a56ddee6c1538cf21363c30cbae/dropwizard-core/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/server/AbstractServerFactory.java).

```
handler.addServlet(new NonblockingServletHolder(new AdminServlet()), "/*");
```

[NonblockingServletHolder](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/2655ac703a0f6ddb4eae933a74dae3d12fde287f/dropwizard-jetty/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jetty/NonblockingServletHolder.java) is the one which is providing the config to `AdminServlet` but is created by `AbstractServerFactory` with empty constructor and provides no way to change the config.

I've thought of and tried to access the ServletHolder from the `Environment` object on `Application.run` method but the admin servlets are not created until after `run` method is run.

```
environment.getAdminContext().getServletHandler().getServlets()[0].setInitParameter("healthcheck-uri", "/health");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in your `run()` function will help you control the URI of your healthchecks:

```
environment.servlets().addServlet(
      "HealthCheckServlet", 
      new HealthCheckServlet(environment.healthChecks())
 ).addMapping("/health");
```

If you want to actually control what's returned you need to write your own resource file. Fetch all the healthchecks from the registery, run them and return whatever aggregated value you want based on their results.

Comment: I tried this, it works perfectly well.  For the simple server type, the mapping is relative to the applicationContextPath.